# Using prevNext Modx Addon

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

I need to display previous and next resource with tv in one parent using this addon in modx

http://modx.com/extras/package/prevnext

But there is some simple documentation, and i can see it has a lot of options, is it posible that someone can show me simple example of tlp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://modx.com/extras/package/prevnext shows clear description and parameters.

```
[[!prevNext]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [pdoNeighbors](http://docs.modx.pro/en/components/pdotools/snippets/pdoneighbors) (part of pdoTools) - it has better documentation and examples.